# Comparing values between two tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, execution-plan

How to compare values between two different tables?

I have two tables as shown below:

```
Table 'A'
sql_id       OPERATION       OPTIONS 
63kf3an2j0pk SELECT STATEMENT
63kf3an2j0pkc TABLE ACCESS FULL

Table 'B'
sql_id       OPERATION     OPTIONS
63kf3an2j0pk SELECT STATEMENT
63kf3an2j0pkc INDEX UNIQUE SCAN IDX_THU
```

I need to compare the values in Table 'A' and Table 'B' for the given `sql_id`. My question is how to find the changed values.

In this case in Table 'A' the second line is `TABLE ACCESS FULL`. Table 'B' the the second line is `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN IDX_THU`. So here the value has changed. How can I find that using query? Something like when matched then "matched" when not changed "value changed".

I'm looking for output something like below:

```
 sql_id           comaparion outcome
dmqb1hzrf5uxh   No change in the plan
74anujtt8zw4h   plan changed
```

Can I do something like this?

```
select sql_id,case when ( select sql_id,OPERATION,options  from  a where sql_id='dmqb1hzrf5uxh'
minus
 select sql_id,OPERATION,options from  b where sql_id='dmqb1hzrf5uxh') is null then 'matched'  else 'changed' end as status;
```

I am comparing the **explain plans** before and after patch. The table 'A' is before patch result of the `sqlid` and table 'B' is after patch result. Now I want to compare the plans in both the tables. I want to compare the plan by using a query.

Comment: I am comparing the explain plans before and after patch.the table 'A' is before patch result of the sqlid and table 'B' is after patch result.Now i want to compare the plans in both the tables.I want to compare  the plan by using a query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sql_id` has a unique or primary key constraint, you can do this with `FULL JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN` if there are no new "inserts" in table B, or just `JOIN` if there are no inserts and no deletions):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.sql_id,b.sql_id) AS sql_id,
    CASE WHEN a.operation = b.operation THEN 'matched' 
         WHEN a.operation <> b.operation THEN 'value changed'
         WHEN b.operation IS NULL THEN 'a deleted'
         WHEN a.operation IS NULL THEN 'b inserted' 
    END AS status,
    a.operation AS a_operation,
    b.operation AS b_operation
FROM 
  a FULL JOIN b
      ON a.sql_id = b.sql_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the differences, use the EXCEPT operator (SQL Server):

```
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM TableB
ORDER BY sql_id
```

When you suspect data was deleted from TableA, you also need to reverse the tables:

```
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM tableB
UNION
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM TableB
EXCEPT
SELECT sql_id, OPERATION, OPTIONS
FROM TableA
ORDER BY sql_id
```

Comment: Did you even try this code? You're missing `SELECT` in a few places. And `EXCEPT` doesn't work on Oracle: you need to use `MINUS` there.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the example from the top of my head. I updated it to be fully executable.

Comment: Your code still uses `EXCEPT`.

Comment: can i do it using UNION ALL select sql_id,operations,options from table a union all select sql_id,operations,options from table b so i will get both the plans the do a comparison there and return the result as shown in the post.is it possible that way

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * from (    
    SELECT sql_id, operations, options AS options_a, STR(null) as options_b from table_a
    UNION
    SELECT sql_id, operations, NULL AS options_b, options as options_b from table_b 
    ) tmp
GROUP BY sql_id, operations 
HAVING( options_a != options_b
  OR    options_a IS NULL 
  OR    options_b is NULL )
```

This should reasonably quickly for smaller sets of data.

For larger sets you can use an outer join to table_b on the first inner query, and a NOT EXISTS in table_a clause on the second second inner query.  This will allow you to drop the GROUP BY line and change HAVING to WHERE.