# Validation of Column value data to Other table column value

Tags: oracle

I have 2 Tables, 1st is the source table which contains City name and 2nd Table is staging table also contains City name and I want to validate the city name for each row in 2nd table is valid or not from Table 1.

For this i have used For Loop but its taking a lot of time so i want to tune this query. Please suggest. Below in the sample query, CITY_VALIDATION_MV is materlized view having aroung 45lakh records and tbl_stg is staging table having > 10k records

```
FOR p IN 
        (
            SELECT  b.row_id ROW_ID, b.country COUNTRY, b.UPPER_TXT_CITY CITY
            FROM tbl_stg b
        )
    Loop
         SELECT stg.Row_Id,
            NVL(
                (
                    SELECT s.mapped_value
                    FROM CITY_VALIDATION_MV s
                    WHERE S.COUNTRY = P.COUNTRY
                        AND S.NAMEUPPER = stg.UPPER_TXT_CITY 
                        AND rownum=1
                ),
                (
                    SELECT B.CITYID
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  s.country COUNTRY
                        FROM CITY_VALIDATION_MV s
                        WHERE S.COUNTRY = P.COUNTRY
                            AND s.nameupper = p.CITY
                        GROUP BY s.country
                    ) A,
                    (
                        SELECT s.state STATE,s.country COUNTRY,s.mapped_value CITYID
                        FROM CITY_VALIDATION_MV s
                        WHERE S.COUNTRY = P.COUNTRY
                            AND S.NAMEUPPER = P.City
                            AND rownum      =1
                    ) B
                    WHERE A.Country=B.Country
                        AND rownum     =1
                )
            ) CITY_ID INTO vRowid, vCityId
            FROM Tbl_Stg stg
        Temp_Table(Vcount).Row_Id := Vrowid;

        Temp_Table(Vcount).City_Id := Vcityid;
        Temp_Table.Extend(1, Vcount);

        Vcount := Vcount+1;    


    End Loop;
```

Comment: What makes a name "valid"? Sounds as if a simple join would do what you want

Comment: Why LOOP? simple LEFT JOIN by city name - NULL value means that this city value not found in cities list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing values between two tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75789/comparing-values-between-two-tables)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find the cities in the stage table that do not appear in the validation table with `EXCEPT` operator (called `MINUS` in Oracle). No need for loops or multiple subqueries:

```
SELECT country, upper_txt_city
FROM tbl_stg
MINUS
SELECT country, nameupper
FROM CITY_VALIDATION_MV ;
```

If you want data from other columns in stage (or to count how many rows don't appear in validation) you can use `NOT EXISTS` (or `LEFT JOIN`/`IS NULL` check):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM tbl_stg  s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM CITY_VALIDATION_MV  v  
        WHERE v.country = s.country
          AND v.nameupper = s.upper_txt_city
      ) ;
```

---

I would expect a composite index on `(country, city)` on both tables increase efficiency of these queries.